# React composition: expose higher-order methods

Tags: reactjs

Since I've seen React team have discouraged developers to use inheritance, I'm trying to use composition instead.

```js
export class Page extends React.PureComponent {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return !isEqual(nextProps, this.props) || !isEqual(nextState, this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onNextClick: () => dispatch(customAction())
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page);


export class FirstPage extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <Page>
                <div>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onNextClick}>Next</Button>
                </div>
            </Page>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onNextClick: () => dispatch(customAction())
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FirstPage);
```

In this case, several components will use Page as container and will have a next button. I'd like to expose a generic handler for the next button click in the Page component to avoid repeating the `dispatch(customAction())`.
I would easily achieve this with inheritance but I'm stuck with the composition pattern.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to provide additional prop for `Page` children:

```
export class Page extends React.PureComponent {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return !isEqual(nextProps, this.props) || !isEqual(nextState, this.state);
    }

    render() {
        const {onNextClick} = this.props;
        return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {onNextClick});
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onNextClick: () => dispatch(customAction())
    }
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Page);


export class FirstPage extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <Button onClick={this.props.onNextClick}>Next</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Page>
                <FirstPage />
            </Page>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so obvious! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) to refer to the `Page` element.

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
  nextHandler(){
    console.log("I am in the parent.");
  }
  
  render(){
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class FirstPage extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Page ref={ page => this.page = page }>
        <div>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <button onClick={ () => this.page.nextHandler() }>Next</button>
        </div>
      </Page>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FirstPage />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's an approach but I don't find it very elegant. Thank you anyway.